# Merging WAV files in c#

Tags: c#, merge, wav, naudio

I am working on Regional Language Text to Voice converter in C#. I have wav files for individual characters.

I want to merge them to get a resultant word's single WAV file.

Im using NAudio library.  It supports the concatenate method which takes outputFile and IEnumerable string sourceFiles as arguments.

But when I execute the method I get NullArgumentException in the line which creates WavFileReader object.

But I have a passed a string of array containing filepaths and an existing empty output wavfile as arguments. I am stuck here.

Could you please suggest me how to use this method,as in how to call this method? and what arguments to use...

Comment: This question looks like it might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6777340/how-to-join-2-or-more-wav-files-together-programatically

Comment: And this article: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15187/Concatenating-Wave-Files-Using-C-2005

Comment: _"But when I execute the method I get NullArgumentException in the line which creates WavFileReader object."_ - so show the code and the variable being null, or debug and fix it yourself.

Comment: @sneha Please include the code that you have, and indicate which line the error is being thrown on.

Answer (score 0):

There is no Concatenate method in NAudio. I assume you are referring to my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6778791/7532). The output WAV file should not already exist - it will be created for you. But the most common cause for an ArgumentNull exception is a null parameter being passed into the function. Are you completely sure your source files array does not contain a null. (adding the stack trace of the exception to your question might help us diagnose further).