# how to concatenate 2 wave files in Stream?

Tags: c#, naudio

I worked on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6778791/4935756) for my problem.
I want that 2 wave files that get of database with byte array type concatenate together and play then dispose it!

this is my code:

```
 public static void Play()
 {
     List<byte[]> audio = dal.SelectSound("خدمات", "احیاء");

     byte[] sound = new byte[audio[0].Length + audio[1].Length];

     Stream outputSound = Concatenate(sound, audio);

     try
     {
           WaveFileReader wavFileReader = new WaveFileReader(outputSound);
           var waveOut = new WaveOut(); // or WaveOutEvent()
           waveOut.Init(wavFileReader);
           waveOut.Play();
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
           Logs.ErrorLogEntry(ex);
      }
}

 public static Stream Concatenate(byte[] outputFile, List<byte[]> sourceFiles)
 {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

        Stream streamWriter = new MemoryStream(outputFile);

        try
        {
            foreach (byte[] sourceFile in sourceFiles)
            {
                Stream streamReader = new MemoryStream(sourceFile);

                using (WaveFileReader reader = new WaveFileReader(streamReader))
                {
                    int read;
                    while ((read = reader.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
                    {
                        streamWriter.Write(buffer, 0, read);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return streamWriter;
    }
```

but I get this error:

> Not a WAVE file - no RIFF header

after execute this line:

```
WaveFileReader wavFileReader = new WaveFileReader(outputSound);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use WaveFileWriter to create a new wave file.

Comment: WaveFileWriter is just for write on disk!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

WAV files are not simply an array of bytes, each WAV file has a 44-byte header (the RIFF header) to tell any software how to play it back. Among other things, this header contains information about the length of the file, so in concatenating two WAV files the way you're doing it, you'll end up with two big problems. Firstly, the first WAV file will still have its old header at the start, which will tell your software that the file shorter than it actually is, and secondly, the header of the second WAV file will be stuck in middle of your new file, which will probably sound very strange if you play it back!

So when you're concatenating your files, you'll need to do the following:

1. Remove the first 44 bytes of each file
2. Concatenate the two byte
   arrays
3. Create a new header according to the [RIFF header specification](http://www.topherlee.com/software/pcm-tut-wavformat.html)
4. Put this header at the
   front of your concatenated byte arrays
5. Call `WaveFileReader wavFileReader = new
   WaveFileReader(outputSound);`

Comment: Thanks, very useful answer however I solved my problem with another quite simple solution ;-)

Comment: @amirstack, could you please provide the solution

Comment: @BabuJames I'm not sure that my solution is useful for you, but I don't join wav files! I play first file then play second file, and also use of CSCore library for not overlapping voice files in certain circumstances. say me if this solution useful for you and want more description.

Comment: I removed header from the second WAV/RIFF and increased the file size of the first header - players play only the first audio in that combined file, file size is increased, but even in `ffprobe` I see the duration of only first audio :(