# Concatenating Audio using NAudio

Tags: c#, .net, naudio

I am trying to concatenate multiple audio files together using NAudio.

I have collection of byte arrays, where the byte arrays represent the individual audio tracks.

```
var samples = new List<ISampleProvider>();

  foreach (var item in collection) {
    ISampleProvider tempAudio = new RawSourceWaveStream(new MemoryStream(item), new WaveFormat()).ToSampleProvider();
    samples.Add(tempAudio);
  }

  var playlist = new ConcatenatingSampleProvider(samples);

  WaveFileWriter.CreateWaveFile("playlist.wav", playlist.ToWaveProvider());
```

However, the audio that is saved to the file "playlist.wav" does not sound like the audio before attempting to concatenate it. The audio sounds much faster and incoherent.

Comment: Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6778791/6923568). It doesn't use `ConcatenatingSampleProvider` but it should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

What audio format are the "items" in collection? The `WaveFormat` you provide to `RawSourceWaveStream` must *exactly* match the audio in `item`. You're just creating a default `WaveFormat` which IIRC is going to be 44.1kHz 16 bit stereo