# Insert an audio file after another audio file in .net core

Tags: c#, .net-core

I have some AudioFiles (.wav) and I want to merge them so that it first plays file1 then file2 and so on.
I tried to use NAudio but I seems it dosn't work in .net core 5 (If I'm wrong, please someone explain).

[image]

and I tried to use [this sample](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/35725/C-WAV-file-class-audio-mixing-and-some-light-audio)  but it merges the file together and all the files play simultaneously. What should I do?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to join 2 or more .WAV files together programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6777340/how-to-join-2-or-more-wav-files-together-programmatically)

Comment: it use NAudio that dosn't work in .net core at least i tried to use and install that from nuget but in depndecies in visual studio show errors.@zainulabidin

Comment: [FYI](https://markheath.net/post/naudio-1-10-net-core-3): The library author's post from 2020 says that it supports .NET Core.

Comment: yes it work in .net core 3 but i use .net core 5 @DiplomacyNotWar

Comment: You mean you've tested it and it doesn't work with .NET 5? That seems odd. It's even mentioned [here](https://github.com/naudio/NAudio/issues/711#issuecomment-739585660) that that should be fine.

Comment: No I say in question  it merge file together and all files play together. but i want to merge  Asynchronous.

Comment: yes i test it and doesn't work

Comment: Perhaps because you're using "merge" when you mean "concatenate"? Did you try [this example?](https://github.com/naudio/NAudio/blob/master/Docs/ConcatenatingAudio.md)

Comment: i am saying that i can't use NAudio in .net 5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i realized that i should select windows in target platform because NAudio just works in Windows and only NAudio.core is crossplatform.

Comment: You are welcome to check it at answered.